# Update value dependent on values matching and using index as reference

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given 2 dataframes:

```
df_team = pd.DataFrame({
    'Team': ["Cal", "Bos", "Flo", "NY", "KC",],
    'Con Team: ["California", "Boston", "Florida", "New York", "Kansas City",],
})

df_sched = pd.DataFrame({
    'Team': ["Bos", "NY", "KC",],
})
```

I would like to perform a certain logic. When the 'Team' name from df_sched is found, convert the value in df_sched to the 'Con Team' in the same index location.

```
results = np.where(df_sched['Team'].isin(df_team['Team']), df_sched['Con Team'], "False")
```

I have just been attempting to put into a list in the time being just to try and understand the logic. When I have the true statement as a string, I am getting the results of at least knowing the search is correct. I Just now need it to convert the value in df_sched['Team'] to the value in df_team['Con Team']. Still learning python at the moment so sorry if easy solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`pandas.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) function to match `'Team'` column values between 2 dataframes:

```
df_sched['Team'].map(dict(zip(df_team['Team'], df_team['Con Team'])))
```

---

```
0         Boston
1       New York
2    Kansas City
```

Comment: Perfect! Applied the results back to the df_sched['Team'] column and worked flawlessly.